# Display fields as defined in data config file in result query in SOLR

Tags: sorting, solr

I am still new to SOLR and I've managed to install and index 1000 documents from the database. When I submit a query, the results are returned correctly but the order of the fields are not displayed as how it is defined in the data config file.

Example of data config file:

```
<field column="id" name="event_id" />
<field column="event_desc_current" name="event_desc" />
<field column="event_cost" name="event_cost" /> 
<field column="event_sponsors" name="event_sponsors" />
...
```

Example of results returned:

```
<result name="response" numFound="7" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="event_desc">Church Fund Raising</str>
    <arr name="event_sponsors">
      <str/>
    </arr>
    <str name="event_id">2</str>
    <int name="event_cost">428</int>
    ...
    <long name="_version_">1472652516366745600</long></doc>
```

How can I output the order of the fields as defined in the data config file like this:

```
event_id
event_desc
event_cost
event_sponsors
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the order of the fields should not matter, as you would de-serialize it in a client and the logic of displaying the search results is with the client.

However, if you do want to dictate the order of fields, you could use the [`fl`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) parameter in your Solr query to get results in the order you prefer.

You could also choose which fields to include in the search field.

Personally, I would recommend that you need not worry about order of fields, and have a client that can consume it in any order. Reason being, if you add a new field to your schema, in the middle, you could potentially breaking the client's logic!

Comment: I tried this in solrconfig.xml <str name="fl">event_id,event_desc,event_cost,event_sponsors</str> - I am still not getting the order I want. Am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: I meant pass `fl=foo,bar,blah` as part of your querystring of the http request to solr..